# Firebase returns "permission_denied" after a while?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have developed a bot that does a "hearbeat" towards my firebase. With this I mean: Every 10 seconds my bot updates an entry in my Firebase with the current time, letting my website know that this was the last time the bot was online.

**Code**

```
function heartbeat() {
    var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    fb.child("bot").set({
        heartbeat: time
    });
}
```

PS: Don't mind it being divided by 1000, there's other reasons for that ;)

**The issue**, however, is that after a while doing this (about a couple of hours), the bot losses (?) it's permissions? And gets the error:

```
"FIREBASE WARNING: set at <path> failed: permission_denied".
```

When I restart the bot, everything works again?

Is there some kind of limitations I'm missing? I'm using the "free plan" at the moment, and thought maybe this could be the reason, but I can't see why any of the limitations of my plan should effect this script?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a simple case of session length. In your firebase dashboard go to the Login & auth tab and session length should be in the top right. Can you check that?

Comment: Ah, I see. Session length is set to 24 hours, which would make sense.

Is there any way for me to say that the "admin user" should have a longer session time? The bot uses a "secret" to authenticate?

Thanks!

Comment: Saying some user has a longer session time isn't possible but you can use a custom token and set the session time for that token. Not really my expertise but take a look at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html.

Comment: Secrets don't expire, so I have a hard time understanding what is happening. Can you add the code of how you authenticate?

Comment: Actually, a complete repro (minus your secret of course) is really the bare mininum to help here. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As Andrè commented this is most likely an issue woth the session length located in my "Login & Auth"-tab.

As he said, there's no way to extend my session length without expanding every users session (yes, there are users logging in to my site, and I don't want them to be logged in any longer).

Therefor: My simple solution to this problem is to change the bot to restart at a specific time when there are little to none users on the site :)

Comment: This doesn't make sense if using a secret, which is noted in your comments as the way the bot authenticates. If you want to generate a long-lived token, you should just [sign your own](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-custom). It's not difficult, in fact, [it's trivial](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/embedded/result/).